# C# GDI+ Image Resize Function

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, resize

So my logic is flawed and I need a better and correct way to resize an image in my c# app

I need a function similar to this setup

```
public void ResizeImageForWeb(string OriginalFile, string NewFile, int MaxWidth, int MaxHeight, int Quality)
{
// Resize Code

}
```

Basically, I'm a web designer lost trying to programming a desktop app.

Comment: Quality of the image, 1 to 100 on how the jpg is compressed

Comment: note that you're asking about a GDI+ Resize function written in C#, not a C# Resize function.

Comment: Thanks, I saw you updated the title, so I added a little more to it as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A quick search from Google find this little [snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4336).

Comment: This is the snippet I use in this case.  +1.

Comment: How can I make the file size smaller using that function?

Comment: @Tyler, that snippet is using the same functions my code uses (Image.GetThumbnailImage, Image.Save) and is therefore going to have the same limitations.

Comment: +1 The "Flip" image trick was what I was the missing part I was looking for. Makes the image much higher resolution. Otherwise you get a blurry image.

Comment: Please don't post links to snippets, they tend to go missing (as this one has...)

Answer (score 8):

This is code I've used to resize images that users upload to either create a thumbnail or simply to enforce a size restriction. It doesn't address picture quality, but it's a start.

```
// uses System.Drawing namespace
public class ImageResizer
{
    public bool ResizeImage(string fullFileName, int maxHeight, int maxWidth)
    {
        return this.ResizeImage(fullFileName, maxHeight, maxWidth, fullFileName);
    }

    public bool ResizeImage(string fullFileName, int maxHeight, int maxWidth, string newFileName)
    {
        using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(fullFileName))
        {
            int height = originalImage.Height;
            int width = originalImage.Width;
            int newHeight = maxHeight;
            int newWidth = maxWidth;

            if (height > maxHeight || width > maxWidth)
            {
                if (height > maxHeight)
                {
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    float temp = ((float)width / (float)height) * (float)maxHeight;
                    newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(temp);

                    height = newHeight;
                    width = newWidth;
                }

                if (width > maxWidth)
                {
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    float temp = ((float)height / (float)width) * (float)maxWidth;
                    newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
                }

                Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort abort = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
                using (Image resizedImage = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, abort, System.IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    resizedImage.Save(newFileName);
                }

                return true;
            }
            else if (fullFileName != newFileName)
            {
                // no resizing necessary, but need to create new file 
                originalImage.Save(newFileName);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It resizes a 1.8 MB image to 1MB when its only 800 pixels wide, any way to make the file size smaller?

Comment: Perhaps look at other overloads of the Save method 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ex6sdew(v=VS.100).aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: The picture quality is terrible! The resize works nicely, but just cant use this.

Answer (score 5):

I would certainly not use GetThumbnailImage as it would be shocking - for good resolution without resorting to DX or OpenL etc, I'd use something like the following (from my own graphics library I use in many windows apps - I have shared this a few times before so there may be variants float around the net). There are 3 methods here - the GetNonIndexedPixelFormat method is used to stop GDI crashing when passed pixel formats it can't handle (comments explain it). The first allows scaling by a factor (Zoom) and the last allows fixed size rescaling whilst keeping the aspect ratio (but can easily be modified if you want to skew it instead). Enjoy:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Scale Image By A Percentage - Scale Factor between 0 and 1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalImg">Image: Image to scale</param>
    /// <param name="ZoomFactor">Float: Sclae Value - 0 to 1 are the usual values</param>
    /// <returns>Image: Scaled Image</returns>
    public static Image ScaleByPercent(Image originalImg, float ZoomFactor)
    {    
        int destWidth = (int)((float)originalImg.Width * ZoomFactor);
        int destHeight = (int)((float)originalImg.Height * ZoomFactor);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, GetNonIndexedPixelFormat(originalImg)); // PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        bmPhoto.SetResolution(originalImg.HorizontalResolution,  originalImg.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(originalImg,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, originalImg.Width, originalImg.Height),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the closest non-indexed pixel format
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalImage">Image: Original image</param>
    /// <returns>PixelFormat: Closest non-pixel image format</returns>
    public static PixelFormat GetNonIndexedPixelFormat(Image originalImage)
    {
        /*
         * These formats cause an error when creating a GDI Graphics Oblect, so must be converted to non Indexed
         * Error is "A graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format"
         * 
            PixelFormat.Undefined 
            PixelFormat.DontCare 
            PixelFormat.1bppIndexed
            PixelFormat.4bppIndexed
            PixelFormat.8bppIndexed
            PixelFormat.16bppGrayScale
            PixelFormat.16bppARGB1555
         * 
         * An attempt is made to use the closest (i.e. smallest fitting) format that will hold the palette.
         */

        switch (originalImage.PixelFormat)
        {
            case PixelFormat.Undefined: 
                //This is also the same Enumation as PixelFormat.DontCare:
                return PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
            case PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed:
                return PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555;
            case PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed:
                return PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555;
            case PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
                return PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555;
            case PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
                return PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555;
            case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
                return PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;                
            default:
                return originalImage.PixelFormat;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resize image keeping aspect ratio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalImg">Image: Image to scale</param>
    /// <param name="Width">Int: Required width in pixels</param>
    /// <param name="Height">Int: Required height in pixels</param>
    /// <param name="BackgroundColour">Color: Background colour</param>
    /// <returns>Image: Scaled Image</returns>
    public static Image Resize(Image originalImg, int Width, int Height, Color BackgroundColour)
    {
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;

        float nPercent = 0f;

        float nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)originalImg.Width);
        float nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)originalImg.Height);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
            destX = System.Convert.ToInt16(((float)Width - ((float)originalImg.Width * nPercent)) / 2f);
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
            destY = System.Convert.ToInt16(((float)Height - ((float)originalImg.Height * nPercent)) / 2f);
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(originalImg.Width * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(originalImg.Height * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height, GetNonIndexedPixelFormat(originalImg)); // PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        bmPhoto.SetResolution(originalImg.HorizontalResolution, originalImg.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.Clear(BackgroundColour);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(originalImg,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, originalImg.Width, originalImg.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for reporting the code here and not link to a external resource that might expire over time. In fact, the link in the accepted answer does not work anymore.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Graphics.DrawImage(). GetThumbnailImage() will return a 120x120 (or smaller) embedded thumbnail from an jpeg file. It will be horrible for anything above that size.

See http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/ for the appropriate settings to use.