# Change image size with C# in MVC3?

Tags: c#, .net, image, asp.net-mvc-3

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddImage(Image model)
{
   if (model.ImageData != null && model.ImageData.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.ImageData.FileName);
      var pathBig = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages"), fileName);
      var pathSmall = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages"), "small_" + fileName);


      // --> How to change image size to big(800 x 600)
     //      and small (100x80) and save them?

      model.ImageData.SaveAs(pathBig);
      model.ImageData.SaveAs(pathSmall);
   }
}
```

How do I change the image size to big(800 x 600) to small (100x80) and save them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this library:
http://nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer

It does support asp.net-mvc:
http://imageresizing.net/

Or you could get a pure C# lib and use it on your app. See these posts:
[Resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861813/368070

And this snippet I found : http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4336

Comment: Thanks, ImageResizer from nuget is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing it from the framework methods itself will be to use the [DrawImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) method of the Graphics Class.

The example code could be like:

```
//For first scale
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(800, 600);
Graphics gf = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
Image userpic = Image.FromStream(/*pass here the image byte stream*/)
gf.DrawImage(userpic, new Rectangle(0,0,800,600))
gf.Save(/* the save path */);

//For second scale
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 80);
Graphics gf = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
Image userpic = Image.FromStream(/*pass here the image byte stream*/)
gf.DrawImage(userpic, new Rectangle(0,0,100,80))
gf.Save(/* the save path */);
```